# Need to select a record within a table based on value with Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

Newbie to selenium and html. I have been using selenium to automate some tasks that can get a little time consuming. Anyways, what I want my program to do is to look at a table of users and select the user based on the name. I have tried many things with no luck. Here is what a record in the table looks like

```
<tr name="1234" id="AvailableUsers" class="FSDocTableRow" 
       onclick="FSListCtrl_MultiSelect(this)"  
       onmouseover="FSListCtrl_ChangeHiLiteRowColour(this, false)" 
       onmouseout="FSListCtrl_ChangeHiLiteRowColour(this, true)" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
   <td><img alt="" src="Images/Icons/UserIcon.gif" border="0">username1-obo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(User)
   </td>
</tr>

<td><img alt="" src="Images/Icons/UserIcon.gif" border="0">username1-obo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(User)
</td>
```

This table has hundreds of records. I want to be able to go into selenium with a variable set to Username1 and be able to find it within this table and click it.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you add what you have tried so far in Selenium, capture of the recording or code?

Comment: Can't you mix non-selenium code in with the selenium code and use ADO.Net or any convenient data access platform from c#?

Comment: Have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686428/how-to-click-on-a-button-within-a-datagrid-after-finding-the-correct-username-in/41687237#41687237