# Web Table handling Selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have several rows and two columns. The column names are Town and country. I need to find the country "UK" in the column and click on the town in the adjacent row. Please tell me how to do it?

[image: The table structure looks like below]

Comment: Hi Tanya! If possible please post `html` directly in the question. Image sharing sites are often blocked on networks, like mine, and the link can go stale. I was able to look on my phone though, so no worries :) Cheers!

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686428/how-to-click-on-a-button-within-a-datagrid-after-finding-the-correct-username-in/41687237#41687237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xpath` allows you to traverse back up the tree, in this case using the `ancestor` axes. Try this:

```
IWebElement town = By.Xpath("//*[@headers='ctry'][text()='UK']/ancestor::tr//*[@headers='twn']/a");
```

Then you can just click it:

```
town.Click();
```

Comment: @Tanya Great! If you feel inclined, feel free to click the check next to the answer to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TableDriver extension to .NET WebDriver (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.NET).  While the long, xpath expression shown in the accepted answer will work, its not very readable.  With TableDriver, you can do it like this:

```cs
Table table = Table.Create(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table.ColorTable")));
TableCell cell = table.FindCell("Country=UK", "Town");
cell.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Click();
```