# How can I get the XPath of a Button in a cell with a non-unique parent cell

Tags: c#, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am struggling to figure out how to access a button in a table cell. The HTML outline looks like this:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<tr role="row" class="even">
<tr role="row" class="odd>
<tr role="row" class="even">
    <td class="">6/27/2017</td>
    <td>1234567</td>
    <td>USG</td>
    <td>Buy Settlement</td>
    <td class="sorting_1">$1.00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>                                              
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="bellLoadModal(event, '/SettlementAccountReconciliation/Reconcile/df420972-81f8-42ae-8f8c-a7a000737dfe', 'Reconcile Settlement Account')">Reconcile</a>                                                                                                     
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<tr role="row" class="even">
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<tr role="row" class="even">
```

Each tr has the same cell structure except for the information inside is different for every cell.

I am trying to access the link in the last td element however cannot seem to find any xpath that is valid because I do not have a unique parent cell. The '1234567' cell value is a unique identifier but I have not found how to use an XPath for a sibling node.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I always suggest looping through the table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686428/how-to-click-on-a-button-within-a-datagrid-after-finding-the-correct-username-in/41687237#41687237

Comment: @Dazed: Looping is rarely necessary actually, and [certainly not needed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493812/290085).

Comment: @kjhughes Depends on your perspective. If the table is only going to be used once, sure use the simple xpath plan. If there is however reuse, you will be continually writing a new xpath to meet each scenario. Not saying my way is better just that I pass the string I am looking for and I just have to go right or left to click a button withing the same row.

Comment: @Dazed: That's just not true.  For selection, a single, well-design XPath beats procedural looping in every respect other than in familiarity to those who are more comfortable with procedural code.  Also, your statement about robustness speaks not to XPath but to your fluency with it.  All of which is fine up until the point that you publicly make a foolhardy statement such as *I always suggest looping through the table* in response to someone who's asking for an XPath.

Comment: Based on the OP's experience, he may not be aware you can loop through it. Just pointing out an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//tr[td='1234567']/td/a[.='Reconcile']
```

will select the `a` element whose string value is `Reconcile` and which exists in a `tr` that contains a `td` with a string value of `1234567`.

Answer (score 0):

I see to possible solutions for this:

first:
`//a[contains(@onclick, "bellLoadModal")]`. This will have multiple results. Iterate them if you know what link-GUID you're lookin for.

second:
`//tr[@role="row"]/td[1]`. This will result in the nodes with the IDs. Iterate them checking for the ID you're lookin for and then go one node up from the current element and select the 7th child node. This is the one with the link.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is for "the link in the last column of the row whose second column contains "1234567", then that's

```
//tr[td[2] = "1234567"]/td[last()]/a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below XPath should work:

```
(//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-xs']) [last()]
```